# Removing magnifying glass from image

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

Added a function to add magnifying glass (.img-magnifier-glass) on button click. Now I want to remove the glass by clicking "cancel" button. I'm confused on how to write this function to work with the "magnify" function.

I tried to create a function that adds a class, and that class would be "display: none" on ".img-magnifier-glass".

```js
function magnify(imgID, zoom)
{
    var img, glass, w, h, bw;
    img = document.getElementById(imgID);
    /*create magnifier glass:*/
    glass = document.createElement("DIV");
    glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
    /*insert magnifier glass:*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
    /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
    bw = 3;
    w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
    h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;

    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    function moveMagnifier(e)
    {
        var pos, x, y;
        /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
        e.preventDefault();
        /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
        pos = getCursorPos(e);
        x = pos.x;
        y = pos.y;
        /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
        if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) { x = img.width - (w / zoom); }
        if (x < w / zoom) { x = w / zoom; }
        if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) { y = img.height - (h / zoom); }
        if (y < h / zoom) { y = h / zoom; }
        /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
        glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
        glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
        /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
        glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
    }
    function getCursorPos(e)
    {
        var a, x = 0, y = 0;
        e = e || window.event;
        /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
        a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
        /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
        x = e.pageX - a.left;
        y = e.pageY - a.top;
        /*consider any page scrolling:*/
        x = x - window.pageXOffset;
        y = y - window.pageYOffset;
        return { x: x, y: y};
    }
}


function onClick()
{
    magnify("img1", 1.5);
    magnify("img2", 1.5);
    magnify("img4", 1.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="slideshow-container">
      <button onclick = "onClick()" id="btn1" type="button" class="btn"> Zoom In</button>
        <button onclick = "zoomOut()" id= "btn2" type= "button" class="btn" >Cancel</button>
      <div class="img-magnifier-container mySlides">
        <img id = "img1" src="img1.jpg" width="800" height="600">
      </div>
      <div class="img-magnifier-container mySlides">
        <img id = "img2" src="img2.jpg" width="800" height="600" >
      </div>
      <div class="img-magnifier-container mySlides">
        <img id = "img4" src="img4.jpg" width="800" height="600">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what you probably want to do is remove the whole node you created in the `magnify` function from the DOM. Just do what you did in reverse, but you won't need all the css, that will go away with the node. You should also remove the eventListeners you set up at the same time.

Comment: remove node: https://catalin.red/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/ and remove event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the added elements and delete them. Since the zoom script gives them all the class name of `img-magnifier-glass` you can do the following:

```
function zoomOut() {
   var zooms = document.querySelectorAll(".img-magnifier-glass");
   for(var x=0;x<zooms.length;x++) {
      zooms[x].parentNode.removeChild(zooms[x]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ve already did that !
Thanks for the zoomOut function.

This is my external JScript

```html
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
    var img, glass, w, h, bw;
    img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  
    /* Create magnifier glass: */
    glass = document.createElement("DIV");
    glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  
    /* Insert magnifier glass: */
    //img.parentElement.hidden(glass, img);
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  
    /* Set background properties for the magnifier glass: */
    glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
    bw = 3;
    w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
    h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  
    /* Execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image: */
    glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    function moveMagnifier(e) {
      var pos, x, y;
      /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* Get the cursor's x and y positions: */
      pos = getCursorPos(e);
      x = pos.x;
      y = pos.y;
      /* Prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image: */
      if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
      if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
      if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
      if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
      /* Set the position of the magnifier glass: */
      glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
      glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
      /* Display what the magnifier glass "sees": */
      glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
    }
  
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0, y = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /* Get the x and y positions of the image: */
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /* Calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image: */
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      y = e.pageY - a.top;
      /* Consider any page scrolling: */
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      y = y - window.pageYOffset;
      return {x : x, y : y};
    }
  }
  function zoomOut() {
    var zooms = document.querySelectorAll(".img-magnifier-glass");
    for(var x=0;x<zooms.length;x++) {
       zooms[x].parentNode.removeChild(zooms[x]);
    }
 }
```

I used the steps from W3Schools [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp][1]

In my Html file i used a switch to display several images :

```html
function showmob(mob)
{
    document.getElementById("mymob").className = "img_show";

    switch (mob) {
     case "mob1":
    
        document.getElementById("mymob").src="iphone12.jpg";
        zoomOut();
        magnify("mymob", 3);
        break;
    
     case "mob2":
    
        document.getElementById("mymob").src="samsung.jpg";
        zoomOut();
        magnify("mymob", 3);
        break;
     case "mob3":
    
        document.getElementById("mymob").src="p40.jpg";
        zoomOut();
        magnify("mymob", 3);
        break;
     case "mob4":
    
        document.getElementById("mymob").src="xiaomiRedmi.jpg";
        zoomOut();
        magnify("mymob", 3);
        break;
    }
}
```

And also in HTML

```html
<tr>
    <td>iphone 12   </td>
    <td>128 GB  </td>
    <td>TrueDepth   </td>
    <td>LiDAR</td>
    <td>IOS 14  </td>
    <td>1.229,00 €    </td>
    <td><button class="iconbtn" onclick="showmob('mob1')"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>samsung galaxy s20  </td>
    <td>128 GB  </td>
    <td>40MP</td>
    <td>108MP(f1.8/PDAF) + 48MP(f3.5) + 12MP(f2.2)  </td>
    <td>ANDROID 11  </td>
    <td>1.399,00 €    </td>
    <td><button class="iconbtn" onclick="showmob('mob2')"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>huawei P40  </td>
    <td>256 GB  </td>
    <td>32 MP   </td>
    <td>50 + 40 + 12 + 3D Tof M </td>
    <td>ANDROID 11  </td>
    <td>899,00  </td>
    <td><button class="iconbtn" onclick="showmob('mob3')"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></button></td>
    
</tr>
```

Thanks again.
I tried to distribute my solution